# Setting delegate to self for the collection view after present action

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

There are 2 pages in Main.storyboard: `FirstViewController` and `SecondViewController`

There is a button in `FirstViewController`. Here is the button click scope:

```
let controller = SecondViewController()
present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

And there is a collection view component in `SecondViewController`.

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var collectionViewOutlet: UICollectionView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    collectionViewOutlet.delegate = self
    collectionViewOutlet.dataSource = self


    let xib = UINib(nibName: "ViewCell", bundle: nil)
    self.collectionViewOutlet.register(xib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "ViewCellID")

    let v0 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "subView") as! SubViewController
    temp_containerViewController = v0
}
}

extension MainPageViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource,  UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
{
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.myPageList.count
    }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionViewOutlet.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ViewCellID", for: indexPath) as! ViewCell
    let viewController = self.temp_containerViewController
    cell.contentViewOutlet = viewController?.view
    cell.contentViewOutlet.backgroundColor = .brown
    cell.lblOutlet.text = self.myPageList[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return collectionViewOutlet.frame.size
}

func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let index = self.collectionViewOutlet.contentOffset.x / self.collectionViewOutlet.frame.size.width
    self.pageControlOutlet.currentPage = Int(index)
    self.pageControlOutlet.numberOfPages = myPageList.count
}
}
```

but below code gives an error:

```
collectionViewOutlet.delegate = self
```

How can I fix this problem? I have created an outlet for the collection view component as you see above.
Here is the error sentence:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load this line

```
let controller = SecondViewController()
```

From storyboard ( Give it identifier **Second** )

```
let controller = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Second") as! SecondViewController
```

As you have outlets without XIB

Comment: Dear @Sh_Khan how can I write Main.storyboard instead of self.storyboard in your code?

Answer (score 1):

Add a condition in `numberOfItemsInSection` `func`

Step 1.

```
if self.myPageList.count > 0 {

  return self.myPageList.count

}else {

return 0
```

}

Step2. Set identifier

```
let controller = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Second") as! SecondViewController
```

Hope Its Help